# How to inject log instance into net core class Library

Tags: asp.net-core, logging

I'm working into net core identity Server project. in the StartUp class this code create a log object

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
        StaticConfig = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
}
```

the same code is inside the api project. Both IdentityServer and Api needs to call functions from an old Soap service. So i create a new net core class Library called SoapClient to share the functions between the two projects.

this the code to instantiate soapClient from IS and Api projects:

```
SoapClient.Client client = new SoapClient.Client(
  Startup.StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("soapClient:server")
);
```

Now i dont know how to inject the log instance inside SoapClient Library. i Tried this into the
constructor but logger is always null:

```
public Client(string serviceUrl, ILogger<Client> logger = null)
{
        _ServiceUrl = serviceUrl;
        logger.LogDebug("Created");
}
```

if remove the default null to logger parameter, the code does compiler because logger is expected to be passed when the costructor is called from IS project and Api project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use dependency injection for this kind of scenarios. The callers should not be responsible of knowing how to create an instance of SoapClient.Client.

Just register your SoapClient.Client into DI. And naturally you can have both the config (via IOptions) and logger injected automatically.

If for whatever reason you don't want to use DI, the caller will have to have an ILoggerFactory injected and you can create ILogger instances using the ILoggerFactory.

Comment: Thanks, I added this code services.AddTransient<SoapClient.Client>(); into ConfigureServices of the caller application ( the identity server). but still the log is null in SopaClient.Client constructor, am i missing something? public Client(string serviceUrl, string appKey, string userAgent, ILogger<Client> logger = null)

Comment: Try removing the default value for logger parameter and see.

Comment: asp.net core seems to have some interesting behavior in terms of default parameters in constructors. For those parameters (dependencies) it injects an object if the type is explicitly registered in DI, or use the default parameter if it's not. In this case, ILogger<Client> is not explicitly registered.
Just my observation and not validated with any asp.net core officials. But this behavior does make sense to me.

Comment: it does not compile removing delfault null value.

Comment: not sure what build error you are getting however looking at the code you posted in the above comment it won't work - you cannot inject a service which takes non-injectable parameters e.g. ```string serviceUrl``` - DI won't be able to instantiate it. If the parameters are from config, use IOptions pattern to inject them into the constructor instead.

Comment: I have solved, it was wrong to call directly the constructor of SoapClient.Client, i've to create the instance via injection too. So i removed new SoapClient.Client(...) and added the parameter SoapClient soapClient in the constructor of the caller class. when Soap client is created via injection also Ilogger is created correctly.